# Pythagorean Triples x,y,z with z<40

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to solve the question below. I'm still studying the topic but this is the first kind of this question I've come across so I have no idea what to do. I do Markov Eqn is x$^2$+y$^2$+z$^2$=3xyz but don't see how it links to the question. Can anybody help?

[image: Pythagorean Triples]

Answer (score 5):

**Outline:** Apart from the order of the legs, all primitive triples are given by $(s^2-t^2, 2st, s^2+t^2)$ where $s$ and $t$ are relatively prime, of opposite parity, with $s\gt t$.

Concentrate on the hypotenuse $s^2+t^2$,  going systematically through all possibilities.
There are not many. Note that $s^2+t^2$ is odd. It will speed things up if you know that a number that has a prime divisor of the form $4k+3$ cannot be represented as a sum of relatively prime squares.

That eliminates $s^2+t^2=39$. For $s^2+t^2=37$, we have $s=6$ and $t=1$. The numbers $35$ and $33$ and $31$ are not sums of relatively prime squares.  Note that $29$ is such a sum, $s=5$, $t=2$. Continue. The end is nigh.